# How to get Order details through order Id in Infusionsoft

Tags: wordpress, api, infusionsoft

I am using infusionsoft in wordpress. I want to get the order details/Invoice details through order id. what function is used to do so?
I found a function

```
function getInvoiceId($orderId)
```

It fetches only InvoiceId.
But I need all the order details like customer Id, price etc. 
help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some solution though it is not perfect answer.

The following is the example code to use 'dsLoad' function.

```
$returnFields = array('Email', 'FirstName', 'LastName');
$conDat = $app->dsLoad("Contact", 123, $returnFields);
```

dsLoad function is one which fetches required fields from database when we provide table name.

So, Use "Invoice" as table name and required fields as $returnFields array.

Here is the example code.

```
$returnFields = array('Id', 'ContactId', 'JobId');
$invoiceDetails = $app->dsLoad("Invoice", 123, $returnFields);
```